# Statistical Test for Trends in Samples from a Possibly Changing Distribution

Tags: time-series, augmented-dickey-fuller, unevenly-spaced-time-series, test-for-trend, diversity

I have some data of quantitative measurements of the language in books from the years 1800 to 2000. For each year I have between 0 and 50 samples, mostly about 10 samples per year. If I bin the data into decades it looks more or less normally distributed within each decade. It also looks like the mean of the distribution is changing from about the year 1900.

I'm assuming that samples are not correlated (books are not from the same author or publishing house or anything like that, they are more or less random samples of books).

Does anyone have any advice about:

a) What statistical test to run to detect a trend in the population mean
I have looked at using linear regression, Dickey Fuller(on median) and Mann-Kendall (on median). But I'm not sure if they are suitable. For example with the sometimes low sample sizes per year it seems to me that Dickey-Fuller may give a false null as there will be regression to the mean from year to year purely due to statistical noise.

b) How can I detect or estimate when a trend begins?
I don't really have a good idea for this. It doesn't have to be super precise, just to say that there was no detectable trend before X date but there was one after for example.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are measuring? One series or multiple, parallel series? Show us a plot? ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Its heading for publication so I'd rather not show a plot. Its multiple series but I am analysing them individually. Let us say that I am measuring the Type Token Ratio (I don't think the analysis will depend on the specific measurement)

Comment: I see. So [Type-Token ratio](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/19551169_TypeToken_Ratios_what_do_they_really_tell_us) is a kind of diversity measure. Also look into change-point detection (search this site). If you can show us some mock-up data, could still be useful ...